# Flutter onError' handler must return a value assignable to 'bool', but ends without returning a value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and im getting error message like this.

This 'onError' handler must return a value assignable to 'bool', but ends without returning a value. Try adding a return statement

And this is my code

```
Future<void> mLaunchUrl(String url, {bool forceWebView = false}) async {
  if(url.isNotEmpty) {
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url),mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication).catchError((e) {
      log(e);
      log('Invalid URL: $url');
    });
  }else{
    toast('URL is Empty');
  }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue Thank you!

Comment: You should be using onError, not the older catchError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the correct way to handle it.

```
  Future<void> mLaunchUrl(String url, {bool forceWebView = false}) async {
    if (url.isNotEmpty) {
      try {
        final bool canLaunch = await canLaunchUrlString(url);
        canLaunch
            ? launchUrlString(url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)
            : log("Unable to launch, URL in invalid.");
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        log("PlatformException caught: ${e.message}");
      }
    } else {
      log("Unable to launch, URL in empty.");
      // Replace the above-written line with toast.
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved the error message! thank you! 

Answer (score 0):

just add a return value of boolean in catchError:

```
Future<void> mLaunchUrl(String url, {bool forceWebView = false}) async {
  if(url.isNotEmpty) {
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url),mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication).catchError((e) {
      log(e);
      log('Invalid URL: $url');
      return true; //here
    });
  }else{
    toast('URL is Empty');
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you want "true" for "yes, I've handled this, no need to rethrow".  And you should be using onError, not the older catchError.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're not returning anything from the catchError handler.

```
import 'dart:developer';// this is used for log
Future<void> mLaunchUrl(String url, {bool forceWebView = false}) async {
      if (url.isNotEmpty) {
        try {
          await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
        } catch (e) {
          log(e);
          log('Invalid URL: $url');
        }
      } else {
        toast('URL is Empty');
      }
    }
```